# Gunicorn can't connect to socket error [Running in vagrant]

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, django-wsgi

I'm running my django app with gunicorn and ran into a weird issue.

This command doesn't work -

```
(venv)-bash-4.1$ gunicorn myapp.wsgi -b unix:/opt/myapp/var/run/app.sock 
[2016-09-15 06:04:12 +0000] [10100] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
[2016-09-15 06:04:12 +0000] [10100] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2016-09-15 06:04:13 +0000] [10100] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2016-09-15 06:04:14 +0000] [10100] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2016-09-15 06:04:15 +0000] [10100] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2016-09-15 06:04:16 +0000] [10100] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2016-09-15 06:04:17 +0000] [10100] [ERROR] Can't connect to /opt/myapp/var/run/app.sock
```

This one works

```
(venv)-bash-4.1$ gunicorn myapp.wsgi -b unix:/tmp/myapp.sock 
    [2016-09-15 06:04:58 +0000] [10105] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
    [2016-09-15 06:04:58 +0000] [10105] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/tmp/myapp.sock (10105)
    [2016-09-15 06:04:58 +0000] [10105] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    [2016-09-15 06:04:58 +0000] [10110] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10110
    [2016-09-15 06:05:01 +0000] [10105] [INFO] Handling signal: int
```

Provided, I have 777 permissions on /opt/myapp/var/run/ directory. The only difference is the location of socket file.

Update : This app is running in a virtualbox VM started with vagrant and /opt/myapp is mapped using fileshare option.

Comment: Make sure the whole directory structure `/opt/myapp/var/run/` can be accessed by webserver's user.

Answer (score 3):

I just found that socket files can not be created on a virtualbox shared directory.

This link helped me.
https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/231